# How to select persian month from AD in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want get shamsi Month in ad date

for example

I have:

2014-03-25 00:00:00

get this by function:

1393/01/05 
 but My ultimate goal is :

"01" is

Comment: can you share you code with us?

Answer (score 0):

The shamsi date data type is string I mean the datatype of `1393/01/05` is `varchar` or `nvarchar`. So you can not apply SQL date functions on it.

You are using a coded function that it is not a built-in SQL function and returns shamsi date in `varchar` or `nvarchar`. The function returns shamsi date by `"YYYY/MM/DD"` format.

You can solve your problem by using string functions in SQL.

for month use:

```
substring(shamsiDate, 6, 2)
```

for year use:

```
left(shamsiDate, 4)
```

for day use:

```
right(shamsiDate, 2)
```

Comment: I also tried this method. But it's a problem to get the same persian date and apply this command with a query.

Comment: Please share or send me your select query and funtion that convert miladi to shamsi.

Comment: SELECT (info.MiladiToShamsi('2013-08-24'))

Comment: Please share `info.MiladiToShamsi()` implementation. This scalar function should return a `varchar(10)` or `nvarchar(10)` result on `YYYY/MM/DD` or `YYYY-MM-DD` format.